# Roll a die until sum is over 63. Calculate the probability of second last roll

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, game-theory, dice

The question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308020/roll-a-dice-repeatedly-until-the-sum-goes-above-63) question. I'll repeat the question for the sake of completeness:

> Roll a die repeatedly. Say that you stop when the sum goes above 63. What is the probability that the second to last value was X. Make a market on this probability. Ie what is your 90 percent confidence interval.

I was trying to solve it with another approach. Let $T$ denotes the event of termination of the game. Then
$$
1=P(T) = P(T|62)P(62) + ....+P(T|57)P(57)
$$
by the law of total probability.
So the question is to find out what is $P(T|X)$. To obtain $P(T|X)$, we need first to know what is $P(X)$ But I can't find a way to calculate the P(X). Is there any smart way to do it?

Alternatively, is there any rigorous mathematical proof to solve this problem?

Comment: Recursion. $\mathbf{p}_k=(p_k,p_{k-1},p_{k-2},p_{k-3},p_{k-4},p_{k-5},p_{k-6},1)^T$, $\ \ $ $\mathbf{p}_{k+1}=A\mathbf{p}_k$, $A=SJS^{-1}$ and forth.

Comment: $A$ is the matrix of probability of going from $p_{k}$ to $p_{k+1}$？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly speaking the probability you hit any value is $\frac 27$ because the average roll is $\frac 72$.  There is a small perturbation which you can assess from the recursion on the chance you hit any value.  I believe it is very small by this point.  Then if you hit $63$ the chance you go over from there is $1$.  If you hit $62$ the chance you go over from there is $\frac 56$ and so on.  The chance that the next to last value was $63$ is then $\frac 6{21}$, the chance of $62$ is $\frac 5{21}$ and so on.  Given that, you should be able to "make a market".  I don't know how that gives a specific answer.  I could come up with a number of fair bets.

Comment: Is there any mathematical reason that the probability hitting any value is $\frac{2}{7}$?

Comment: @quallenjäger:  because the average roll is $\frac 72$.  If you roll $1000$ times you will advance about $3500$ steps, so you must hit about $\frac 27$ of them.  You can make a recurrence that starts with the chance you hit $1$ is $\frac 16$, the chance you hit $2$ is $\frac 5{36}$ and so on.  It converges rapidly.

Comment: right, I see. And how do you come to the $\frac{5}{21}$ value?

Comment: isn't hitting 2 $\frac{7}{36}$? Because you can roll direct a 2 which is $\frac{1}{6}$ and two 1's which is $\frac{1}{36}$

Comment: Yes, it is $\frac 7{36}$.  Brain glitch.  If you hit $62$ the chance it is the next to last roll is $\frac 56$ because it will be unless you roll a $1$.  If you hit $58$ it will be the next to last roll if you roll a $6$, so probability $\frac 16$.  You scale those up to make the sum $1$ and the denominator is $21$